# How to use my phone number on my Macbook's Messages?

Tags: macos, ios, macbook-pro, messages

iMessage is very confusing as my email and phone number keeps receiving different messages at random occasions rather than having all messages sent to both. This is very apparent in  group messages.

I would like to use my phone number, is this possible ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes - it's entirely possible to have your Mac send and receive iMessage using your iPhone's message as the "caller ID" only.

Setting this up is normally a two step process.

First ensure that your phone with the number you wish all computers to use as your "caller ID" for the Mac has your Apple ID enabled for Messages. Until that device has activated the phone number to your Apple ID account, you can't go to step two.

Next, in the preferences on your Mac, look at the bottom of the pane for that Apple ID and choose to send a message from your Phone number rather than from the Apple ID mail address.

[image: Messages settings on OS X for Jenny]

I prepared that picture for another answer and you might read there in case things are not working. I find it best to set each and every device to send from the **same one string** - whether it's a string of phone digits or a string of email address to avoid having people reply to your non-preferred account. In that case, you can either deal with two conversations or train them to send to your preferred address. It's a bit of tough love, but the most effective way is to only accept messages from your preferred string and then send read receipts. That way people realize some messages do not get delivered and self correct.

Apple has a nice article that covers how things are supposed to work as well as what to do when things don't.

- [iOS: About Messages](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3529)
- [iOS: Troubleshooting Messages](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2755)
- [iOS: Troubleshooting FaceTime and iMessage activation](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4268)

Comment: I added my number but it is stuck at waiting to verify .. nothing is happening. Im using a UK number, so example `0753 123 4567` is a number, do I type it as `+44 0753-` or `0044 0753-` or `+44 753-` ?

Comment: You don't type the number. Messages sends a text SMS message to the device and once it gets delivered, self configures your Apple ID to "own" that phone number. You can ask Apple for support on that or read their troubleshooting article. I'll add both to the answer... You might need your carrier to help if you don't have SMS delivery or need to troubleshoot things, but most people can figure what step is failing from the guides linked above.

Comment: Is this feature only for ios 6 by any chance ?

Comment: Well - the Mac side of things isn't iOS - but iCloud should work on iOS 5 as described above. I've sent and received both numeric and Apple ID messages from iPads and iPhones on iOS 5 many times.

Comment: The number is still stuck at "verifying" btw, it's not working !

Comment: @Render That's no fun. The last link on troubleshooting iMessage activation might help - if not, you always have Apple's support in troubleshooting activation. It's the last item on the page [linked above (and here)](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4268)

Answer (score 1):

I found that by unchecking the box 'enable this account' under my apple ID account and then rechecking it, the messages app registered my phone number as an option for sending and receiving.

Comment: I also didn't have my phone number available to select and this toggle fixed that up perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The steps above are accurate, but only if your phone has allowed your mac as a device (see image below).

So connect to your wifi on your phone and follow the steps below. Then your mac will provide your phone number as an option where you can be reached for messages (as the answer above depicts).

Thankfully this thread helped me to figure out that the issue was with my phone first and not my mac.

[image]